# Using NavigationLink in Menu (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

Can you use a `NavigationLink` as a `Menu`'s item in swiftUI?

It seems to do just nothing:

```
Menu {
   NavigationLink(destination: Text("test1")) {
       Text("item1")
   }
   NavigationLink(destination: Text("test2")) {
       Text("item2")
   }
} label: {
   Text("open menu")
}
```

In case it is meant to not work as tried above, is there an alternative way of achiving the intended reult?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**init(destination:isActive:label:) is deprecated since iOS 16**

> 'init(destination:isActive:label:)' was deprecated in iOS 16.0: use
> NavigationLink(value:label:) inside a NavigationStack or
> NavigationSplitView

`NavigationLink` should be inside `NavigationView` hierarchy. The `Menu` is outside navigation view, so put buttons inside menu which activate navigation link placed inside navigation view, eg. hidden in background.

Here is a demo of possible approach (tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1)

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoNavigateFromMenu: View {
    @State private var navigateTo = ""
    @State private var isActive = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Menu {
                Button("item1") {
                    self.navigateTo = "test1"
                    self.isActive = true
                }
                Button("item2") {
                    self.navigateTo = "test2"
                    self.isActive = true
                }
            } label: {
                Text("open menu")
            }
            .background(
                NavigationLink(destination: Text(self.navigateTo), isActive: $isActive) {
                    EmptyView()
                })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works just fine, I assume that using the isActive binding is the (only/best-practice) approach for navigating to a different view programmatically in swiftUI?

Answer (score 3):

I can say that Asperi's answer is great solution. It helped a lot. But we need a custom view to hold a reference inside the destination property right? not a string.

```
@State var navigateTo: AnyView?
@State var isNavigationActive = false
```

We can hold a reference AnyView type and then call the view like this:

```swift
Menu {
    Button {
        navigateTo = AnyView(CreateItemView())
        isNavigationActive = true
    } label: {
        Label("Create an Item", systemImage: "doc")
    }
    
    Button {
        navigateTo = AnyView(CreateItemView())
        isNavigationActive = true
    } label: {
        Label("Create a category", systemImage: "folder")
    }
} label: {
    Label("Add", systemImage: "plus")
}
```

For more detail please see this post:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/119583