# NavigationView from actionSheet?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Is it at all possible to use an actionSheet with navigationView? I want clicking a button in an actionSheet to take them to a new view.

```swift
                .actionSheet(isPresented: $showingActionSheet) {
                    ActionSheet(title: Text("Login"), message: Text("Choose how to login"), Buttons: [
                        .default(Text("Email and Password")) {
                        //Navigate somewhere using NavigationView
                        }
```

Edit: Was told to do this, but still not working

```swift
                    .actionSheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
                    ActionSheet(title: Text("Login With:"), message: Text("Choose how to login"), buttons: [
                        .default(Text("Email")) { self.navigateTo = "emaillogin" },
                        .default(Text("QR Code")) { self.navigateTo = "QR" },
                        .default(Text("Key")) { self.navigateTo = "keylogin" },
                        .default(Text("Text")) { self.navigateTo = "textlogin" },
                        .cancel()
                    ])
                }
                .background(
                    NavigationLink(destination: Text(self.navigateTo), isActive: $isActive) {
                        EmptyView();
                    })
```

Comment: Approach can be the same as with Menu: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64845327/12299030.

Comment: Am I doing something wrong here? it still isn't working

Answer (score 0):

> Am I doing something wrong here? it still isn't working

It looks like missed link activation:

```
.actionSheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
    ActionSheet(title: Text("Login With:"), message: Text("Choose how to login"), buttons: [
        .default(Text("Email")) { self.navigateTo = "emaillogin"; isActive = true },
        .default(Text("QR Code")) { self.navigateTo = "QR"; isActive = true },
        .default(Text("Key")) { self.navigateTo = "keylogin"; isActive = true },
        .default(Text("Text")) { self.navigateTo = "textlogin"; isActive = true },
        .cancel()
    ])
}
```