# How to trigger a NavigationLink programmatically in a LazyVGrid

Tags: swiftui, lazy-loading, swiftui-navigationlink, lazyvgrid

I have a `LazyVGrid` inside a `NavigationView`.

```
NavigationView {
    ScrollView {
        LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
            ForEach(items) { item in
                NavigationLink(tag: item, selection: $displayedItem) {
                    DetailView(item)
                } label: {
                    GridItemView(item)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The referenced variables are defined as follows on the view:

```
@State var displayedItem: Item?
let columns: [GridItem] = Array(repeating: .init(.flexible()), count: 2)
```

Now I want to show the detail view for a specific item. I do this by simply assigning this item to the `displayedItem` property:

```
func showDetailView(for item: Item) {
    displayedItem = item
}
```

This works great when the respective item is visible on the `LazyVGrid` at the moment when I call this function. However, when the item is not visible, I first need to scroll to the item for the `NavigationLink` to fire. I know why this is happening (because the items are loaded lazily, it's a *lazy* grid after all), but I don't know how to make the `LazyVGrid` load the specific item when I need it.

---

#### What I've tried:

I have also tried to programmatically scroll to the target item by wrapping the entire `ScrollView` inside a `ScrollViewReader` and appending the following modifier:

```
.onChange(of: displayedItem) { item in
    if let item = item {
        scrollProxy.scrollTo(item.id)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this has the same problem: Scrolling to a given item doesn't work until the item is loaded.

---

#### Question:

Is there any way to make this work, i.e. to trigger a `NavigationLink` for an item that is not currently visible in the `LazyVGrid`? (It's important for me as I need this functionality to deep-link to a specific item's `DetailView`.)

Comment: I think you can just render the labels (`GridItemView`) in your grid and have a `NavigationLink` to navigate to the child view., and when the user taps on an item, call a function to set the selected view.

Comment: An possible approach can be like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64845327/12299030 - use one link somewhere in background of ScrollView and activate it by tapGesture/button from user or assigning corresponding value programmatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An possible approach can be like in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64845327/12299030) - use one link somewhere in background of ScrollView and activate it by tapGesture/button from user or assigning corresponding value programmatically.

Tested with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

[image]

Main part:

```
ScrollView {
    LazyVGrid(columns: columns) {
        ForEach(items) { item in
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 16).fill(.yellow)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity).aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
                .overlay(Text("Item \(item.value)"))
                .onTapGesture {
                    selectedItem = item
                }
        }
    }
}
.padding(.horizontal)
.background(
    NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(item: selectedItem), isActive: isActive) {
        EmptyView()
    }
)
.toolbar {
    Button("Random") { selectedItem = items.randomElement() }
}
```

[Test module on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestNavigateLazyGridView.swift)

Comment: NavigationLink *isActivated* is deprecated in iOS 16.
Any idea how to show / trigger navigation link manually then?