# Button Text Out-Of-Sync with Tappable Area

Tags: swiftui, ios15

I have a navigation view with tab views inside. The reason for this arrangement is to make the tab views disappear when within the navigation views.

I am trying to place a button at the top right corner of the screen (outside the safe area). If EntryView is called directly, the view correctly places the button ("Save") in the corner without use of offset() or position() view modifiers.

When the tab view is called before EntryView, the Save button appears an inch or so below where I would like it to appear. With offset() or position() I can move the button text back where I would like it to appear, but the tappable area doesn't move to the new location.

I have tried different arrangements of ZStack and VStack, but the arrangement below is the closest I have come to getting the button to work in the upper right corner.

Here is where I would like the button to appear: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMdKQ.png

Is there any way to move the tappable area up to where the text is located?
Or is there some better way to draw the top part of the view?

This code can be dropped directly into Xcode for analysis.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab: Tabs = .home

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            TabView (selection: $selectedTab) {

                EntryView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("Home", systemImage: "house.circle.fill")
                    }.tag(Tabs.home)


                HistoryView()
                    .tabItem {
                        Label("History", systemImage: "clock.fill")
                    }.tag(Tabs.history)

            }
        }
    }
}


struct EntryView: View {

    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { g in

            ZStack (alignment: .top) {
                Color.blue
                    .frame(height: (g.safeAreaInsets.top) * 0.6, alignment: .top)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()

                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Button(action: {

                        print("Save tapped!")
                    }) {

                        Text("Save")
                            .font(Font.title3.bold())
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                            .offset(y: g.size.height * -0.14)
                        // .position(x: g.size.width * 0.90, y: g.size.height * -0.115)
                    }
                }
                .padding(.trailing, 10)
            }
        }
    }
}


struct HistoryView: View {

    var body: some View {

        VStack (alignment: .leading) {
            Text("History Tab")
                .padding(.top)
        }
    }
}

enum Tabs: String {
    case home
    case history
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just place that button into toolbar? Like, for example, here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72660236/12299030

Comment: Yes, I initially did attempt to use the navigation toolbar but nothing appears to happen. I tried including the toolbar inside and outside the ZStack with no button appearing anywhere. It acts like the tab bar is interfering with the navigation view.

.toolbar {
                   ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {}